# django Bring data from the database for editing

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a form to create a client and another to modify it but the problem is that the modification form does not bring the information of the database.

Bring a basic form without fields with data.

view:

```
def cliente_update(request, id=None):
    queryset = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ClienteForm()
    context = {
        "titulo": "Editar informacion del Cliente",
        "queryset": queryset,
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "clientes/form.html", context)
```

Comment: Where is the code of **ClienteForm**. Please share your forms.py also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your Cliente object through `instance` parameter in your modelform in `else` block.

```
def cliente_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=id)  # renamed from queryset to instance
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = ClienteForm(instance=instance)

    context = {
            "titulo": "Editar informacion del Cliente",
            "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "clientes/form.html", context)
```

Comment: The instance appears to be in the very confusingly named variable `queryset`, which should certainly be renamed.

Comment: I agree, renamed the variable.